# How do you create modules with Vuex and get data with mapState()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I tried separating my Vuex code in modules but I can't get data from `mapState()`.

What is the best way to create modules and use mapping?

I have a store folder:

```
├── store
│   └── index.js
|   └── testStore.js
|
```

In `index.js` I have:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

import { testStore } from './testStore'

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules : {
    testStore,
  }
});
```

in `testStore.js` I have:

```
export const testStore  = 
{
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    mutations,
}


const state = 
{
    social: false,
    normal: true,

};
const mutations = 
{
    // setters
    setSocial(state, payload) {
      state.social = payload;
    },
    setNormal(state, payload) {
        state.normal = payload;
    },
};
```

I have a test component to try it:
(I use Vuetify)

`testComponent.vue`:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-layout justify-center>
        <v-btn class="primary" @click="displaydata">test</v-btn>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>

import { mapState, mapMutations } from 'vuex'

export default {
    computed: {
        ...mapState('testStore',['normal','social']),
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapMutations('testStore',['setNormal','setSocial']),

        displaydata() {
            // eslint-disable-next-line
            console.log(this.normal);
            // eslint-disable-next-line
            console.log(this.social);
        } 
    }
};
</script>
```

When I click on "test" button, the console displays: `undefined`.

So, what is wrong? :(

Comment: Is `testStore.js` really written in that order, with `state` and `mutations` defined after you've already tried to use them? Have you tried inspecting the store in vue-devtools?

Comment: @skirtle ooh, the export was before, my bad, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This have a very simple solution (I hadn´t seen it):

in `testStore.js`, the `export const testStore` was at the begin.

So, the right `testStore.js` is very similar but with `export` at end:

```
const state = 
{
    social: false,
    normal: true,

};
const mutations = 
{
    // setters
    setSocial(state, payload) {
      state.social = payload;
    },
    setNormal(state, payload) {
        state.normal = payload;
    },
};

export const testStore  = 
{
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    mutations,
}
```